# C# Write to text file, including \r\n

Tags: c#

```
s="abc def\r\nghi jkl
```

I'm using the following commands:

```
 foreach (string s in partsAll)
 {
     file.WriteLine(s);
 } 
 file.Close();
```

I'm getting in the file:

```
abc def
ghi jkl
```

I would like to see in file same value including `\r\n`:

```
abc def\r\nghi jkl
```

Tried also with `Write()`. Did not change anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
s = s.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "\\r\\n");
```

or

```
s = s.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, @"\r\n");
```

Edit:
Using Regex

```
string str = "abcdef\nghik\r\nb";
str = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(str,"\r", @"\r"),"\n", @"\n");
```

Comment: Bear in mind, this works differently on Unix, so if the string specifically contains \r\n, it will only replace the \n.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `\r\n`. Have `\\r\\n` in the string instead.

Comment: How? I tried:
        s.Replace(@"\n", @"\\n");
        s.Replace(@"\r", @"\\r");

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
s="abc def\r\nghi jkl";
```

use one of following:

```
s="abc def\\r\\nghi jkl";
```

or

```
s=@"abc def\r\nghi jkl";
```

Comment: Let me clarify. s already contains the string above. I need to manipulate it as is. How can I do it for example with .Replace?